# When revisiting home page, gmaps won't reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have an app using the Google Maps API gem

```
    gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

I have the map on the home page.  The page loads fine when it first loads, then if a go over to another page the content of that page loads, but when I go back to the home page, the previous content remains and the map doesn't load.  If you manually refresh the page it loads normally.

I am pretty sure this is a simple error that I am missing, how do I get the page to refresh when I revisit it?

My homepage code with the scripts is here

```
    <div style='width: 400px;'>
        <div id="map" style='width: 400px; height: 400px;'></div>
    </div>

    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key="" + ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers([
        {
          "lat": -32.023598,
          "lng": 115.859690,
          "picture": {
            "width":  32,
            "height": 32
          },
          "infowindow": "hello!"
        }
      ]);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.getMap().setZoom(16);
    });
    </script>
```

I found a few answers that were kind of similar but I could not get the issue solved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it won't reload even if you click the home (root_path) link.  As you navigate, you open the page and its perfect, click on another page and it loads fine, then click the home link and it doesn't reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems is the turbolink.

Disable turbolink on all link_to the page has map or remove require turbolink on you `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Example:

```
<%= link_to('HOME', root_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) %>
```

Comment: I disabled turbolinks and that worked, however when I tried the link_to option it didn't make any difference.

Are there any repercussions from not using turbolinks?

Comment: Turbolink was used to cache js. In this case, the js on map was load, and It won't load again, It's reason for why when you click link to => map not display but when reload page => map displayed.

Disable turbolink don't affect to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty Anonymous `onunload = function(){}` in your JavaScript on the page you want the code to reload on, then the cache should clear before the page is loaded again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where abouts do I put that and do I just put it as typed or do I put something inside the {}?

Comment: Empty, just like the example.